# oracle convert to number

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I am trying to convert 193 to 1000000193 in oracle. 193 could be any number less than 1000000000

This does not work.

```
select to_char(193,'1000000000') from dual;
```

Comment: So what is the pattern you're trying to follow here?

Answer (score 2):

i suppose this works.

select  '1' || LPAD('193',9,'0') from dual

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted.  Could whoever did it please explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Why can't we add them?

```
select 193+1000000000 from dual;
```